# PHP table data filtering

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to filter data in the table use dropdown menu (e.g. filter by name so i can see all data with name 'Jane'). I don't want to move to another page (use ajax or anything else if can). Any idea what must i do ?

This is the dropdown menu and table code :

```
<!-- Dropdown menu -->
<div class="col-md-2">      
        <select class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option value="">Name</option>
            <?php
                // print all name value from $administratorProvider
                foreach($administratorProvider as $administrator){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php $administrator->first_name ?>"><?php echo $administrator->first_name; ?></option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
</div>

<table>
    <!-- Table heading -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="center">No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Join</th>
            <th>Last Login</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <!-- Table body -->
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $i=1;
            foreach ($dataProvider as $data){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <div>
               <td class="center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $data->email; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $data->join; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $data->last_login; ?></td>
            </div>
         </tr>
         <?php $i++; } ?>
    </tbody>
    <!-- // Table body END -->
</table>
```

Thanks for any advice.
Regards

Comment: Where are the names being populated from, DB, other?

Comment: it's from DB, all names placed in $dataProvider

Comment: @asprin i don't want to do it manually, so i want to use some library if possible

Comment: @asprin do u have any recommendation for some simple library ?

Comment: @Ken you can use dataTable library. http://www.datatables.net

Comment: @MohitArora any example how to implement ? i'm newbie

Comment: here is step by step tutorial :- http://www.sitepoint.com/working-jquery-datatables/  and there are many examples in  http://www.datatables.net/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to achieve this effect quite easily. Make two files: 
**1)** One that includes the table. 
**2)** One that has the select tag that will reload the first file upon change of the `<select>` tag.

Let's call the first file select.php

```
<script>
    // Load the div with the contents of the table.php file with no GET parameter
    $('div').load('table.php');

    $('select').change(function() {
        var name = $(this).val();
        var data = 'name='+ name;

        // Make sure that the table's contents don't change if the first option tag 
        // is selected. 
        if(name != '') {
            $('div').load('table.php', data);
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="col-md-2">      
    <select class="form-control selectpicker">
        <option value="">Name</option>
 <?php
        // print all name value from $administratorProvider
        foreach($administratorProvider as $administrator){
 ?>
        <option value="<?php $administrator->first_name ?>"><?php echo $administrator->first_name; ?></option>
 <?php
        }
  ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

File two can be called table.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '".$name."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {  
   // Save your info as variables
   $name[$i] = $row['name'];
   $email[$i] = $row['email'];
   $join[$i] = $row['join'];
   $login[$i] = $row['last_login'];
}
?>

<div>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="center">No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Join</th>
        <th>Last Login</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php
     for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
 ?>
    <tr>
        <div>
           <td class="center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $name[$i]; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $email[$i]; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $join[$i]; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $login[$i]; ?></td>
        </div>
     </tr>
<?php 
    } 
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>  
</div>
```

Upon change of the select tag, the second file will be loaded with the value of the selected option tag sent to that file as a `GET` variable. You might wanna take the SQL part with a grain of salt as I'm not sure how you're fetching your relevant data.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i dont want to move to another page (use jquery if can since i already get all data from controller), sorry if i don't write all the information that necessary

Comment: jQuery will be loading the contents of the second file. The first file is essentially just the view, the second file will perform all of the functionality.

Comment: sorry my fault, i mean ajax sir

Comment: For the sake of this example, jQuery will essentially be doing the same thing that AJAX would.